# Can I place oracle statements inside of if else statement of sql

Tags: sql

Problem while placing oracle query inside of the oracle if else statements

```
select workgroupid, maxchats, 
      case
        when a.maxchats ='-1' then 
  (select propvalue  from ofproperty where name = 'xmpp.live.defaults.maxchats') 
       else 
          null (1)
        end as aaaa
from fpworkgroup a;
```

when im placing maxchats at 1 position im getting error,,

how can i resolve this....?

help me..
thanks in advance

Comment: Your question does not make sense. Please clarify. What is `(1)`? Where is this `if/else` you're talking about? What is the column type of `ofproperty.propvalue` and of `maxchats`?

Comment: sorry i tried to show position, so i given that number...

Comment: if the a.maxchats = '-1' is true then im executing other query,, 
in else condition i should display maxchats only (in else i need not to go for other query)

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to understand your question but it sounds like you're trying to put `maxchats` in place of `null (1)` and it gives you an error?

If that is correct, I'm guessing that the error is that `fpworkgroup.maxchats` and `ofproperty.propvalue` have different column types that do not line up. All branches of a `CASE` must return the same column type. You cannot, for example, return an `int` from one branch and return a `varchar` from another.

You'll have to cast one or the other so that they return the same type.